What is the purpose of META-INF folder in APK nowadays?
Before everyone flag this question as duplicate or link me every site with an explanation, I am aware that this question has been answered multiple times. That being said, NONE of them is relevant to the current times (at least by the time when this question is asked).
To explain my point I will make an empty views activity using Android Studio Iguana, either build configuration language is fine

I will then proceed to generate a signed APK, and unzip said APK to see the META-INF
└─$ tree META-INF/
META-INF/
├── androidx.activity_activity.version
├── androidx.annotation_annotation-experimental.version
├── androidx.appcompat_appcompat-resources.version
├── androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version
├── androidx.arch.core_core-runtime.version
├── androidx.cardview_cardview.version
├── androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version
├── androidx.core_core-ktx.version
├── androidx.core_core.version
├── androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version
├── androidx.customview_customview.version
├── androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version
├── androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version
├── androidx.dynamicanimation_dynamicanimation.version
├── androidx.emoji2_emoji2.version
├── androidx.emoji2_emoji2-views-helper.version
├── androidx.fragment_fragment.version
├── androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version
├── androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata-core.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-livedata.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-process.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-runtime.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate.version
├── androidx.lifecycle_lifecycle-viewmodel.version
├── androidx.loader_loader.version
├── androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version
├── androidx.print_print.version
├── androidx.profileinstaller_profileinstaller.version
├── androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview.version
├── androidx.savedstate_savedstate.version
├── androidx.startup_startup-runtime.version
├── androidx.tracing_tracing.version
├── androidx.transition_transition.version
├── androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version
├── androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version
├── androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version
├── androidx.viewpager2_viewpager2.version
├── androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version
├── com
│   └── android
│       └── build
│           └── gradle
│               └── app-metadata.properties
├── com.google.android.material_material.version
├── kotlinx_coroutines_android.version
├── kotlinx_coroutines_core.version
├── services
│   ├── kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler
│   └── kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory
└── version-control-info.textproto

6 directories, 46 files

Weird, it doesn't seem to contain any MANIFEST.MF, or CERT.RSA, or CERT.SF like in this explanation, or this explanation, or ANY OTHER EXPLANATION I CAN FIND.
I expected the META-INF folder to contains MANIFEST.MF, CERT.RSA, or CERT.SF file like explained in any other explanation, but it appears to be completely different.
So if anyone can explain what is the purpose of the META-INF folder nowadays, and where does the MANIFEST.MF file go, it will be much appreciated.
